# Python split text on several parts

Tags: python, string, string-length

I have returned from one function as plain multi-line text, which I should print in Telegram or Discord. The problem is the character limit for one message. And text should only be separated by line. E.g.

```
limit = 50

text = "Line1 - some text 
Line2  - some text
Line3 - some text, limit here
Line4 - some text"
```

I need to do smth to get

```
text1 = "Line1 - some text 
Line2  - some text"

text2 = "Line3 - some text, limit here
Line4 - some text"
```

or any other way to separate long string onto several parts, but only by lines.

This is the wrong result:

```
text1 = "Line1 - some text 
Line2  - some text 
Line3 - some"

text2 = "text, limit here
Line4 - some text"
```

Comment: what happens if there is a line over the character limit?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use a regex to break on word boundaries

Comment: In my case, the max string length does not exceed 68 characters. But sometimes the full length of the message exceeds 2000 characters? more than Telegram or Discord limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be something like

```
def send(x):
    #put your sending code here
    print(x)

s = "10\n1\n101\n10\n1" #example input

s= s.split("\n") # divides the string into lines
print(s)
#we want to send as many lines as possible without the total size of the sent string being over limit
limit = 3 #make this whatever you want
sending = ""
total = 0

for line in s:
    if total + len(line) > limit:
        send(sending[:-1])
        total = len(line)
        sending = line + "\n"
    else:
        total += len(line)
        sending += line + "\n"
#need to send the final string; there is probably a better way to do this, especially because this will break if the first if is entered on the last iteration
send(sending[:-1])
```

I suspect theres a better way to do this in just a few lines with some clever splitting or regex, but this is a brute way to split it up into smaller messages by line. Note that this will attempt to send lines that are over the character limit, and it can definitely be improved.

Answer (score 1):

simple example to split data to buffer

```
import re

limit = 50
text = "Line1 - some text\nLine2  - some text\nLine3 - some text, limit here\nLine4 - some text"
tring_array=re.split('(\n)(\r\n)',text)

message=""
for current_str in string_array:
    if (len(message)+len(current_str)+1) <= limit:
        message+=(current_str+'\n')
    else:
        if len(message) == 0:
            print "buffer to smal or empty string"
            break
        else:
            print "Message: %sSize: %d" % (message,len(message))
            message=current_str+'\n'

if len(message)>0:
    print "Message: %sSize: %d" % (message,len(message))
```

results

```
Message: Line1 - some text
Line2  - some text
Size: 37
Message: Line3 - some text, limit here
Line4 - some text
Size: 48
```

Comment: Naming your variables the same name as builtins is bad practice. It can cause hard to debug bugs.

Comment: thanks changed this to a regular variable